# Show that $(A^o)^o = A$ if A is compact and convex.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I am working on exercises for a convex analysis course and I am slightly stuck on the following;

Suppose that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, bounded (compact) and conex. Define the set

$$
A^o = \left\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : y^Tx \leq 1, \forall x \in A\right\}
$$

Show that $A^o$ is convex and $(A^o)^o = A$.

Showing that $A^o$ is convex is easy; take $u,v \in A^o$ and $\theta \in [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then for all $x \in A$ we have

$$
(\theta u +(1-\theta)v)^Tx = \theta u^Tx+(1-\theta)v^Tx \leq \theta + (1-\theta) = 1
$$

and so  $\theta u +(1-\theta)v \in A^o$.

Also showing that $A \subset (A^o)^o$ is easy since for each $x \in A$ and $y \in A^o$ we have

$$
x^Ty = y^Tx \leq 1.
$$

Now showing that $(A^o)^o \subset A$ is where I am getting stuck. The way I've been trying to show this is by contradiction.

I suppose that there exists $x \in (A^0)^0$ so that $x \notin A$. Then let $\xi \in A$ so that

$$
||x-\xi|| = \text{dist}(x,A).
$$

Such a $\xi$ exists since $A$ is compact. Now since $A$ is convex as well as compact we know that the hyperplane

$$
H = \left\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^Ty =b \right\}
$$

with $a = x - \xi$ and $b = \frac{a^Tx+a^T\xi}{2}$ is a strict separating hyperplane for the set $A$ and $\{x\}$ with

$$
x \in \left\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^Ty >b \right\}
$$

and

$$
A \subset \left\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : a^Ty < b \right\}.
$$

Now this is where I get fully stuck. I have tried every which way that I can think of to get a contradiction from here with no success.

How would you suggest going forward.

NOTE: Hints are also welcome, if I get to a proof with the help of a hint then I will post my final proof as the answer to this question.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing in the last part

Comment: You need to add the assumption $0 \in A$, since you always have $0 \in (A^o)^o$. Otherwise, the result does not hold: E.g. for $A = \{1\} \subset \mathbb R$ you have $(A^o)^o = [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: As per the comment of gerw, the claim is only true if $0\in A$.

It seems to me like you already have a good idea with using seperating hyperplanes.

The next step would be to think of $A^\circ$ not just of a set in $\mathbb R^n$ but as a set of hyperplanes/half-spaces.

You have shown that there are $a,b$ such that
$$
A\subset \{y\in\mathbb R^n : a^\top y<b \}.
$$
Since $0\in A$, this implies that $b>0$.
We can change $a,b$ by scaling such that $b=1$.
Then we obtain
$$
 a^\top y < 1 \qquad\forall y\in A
$$
which implies
$$
 a \in A^\circ.
$$
Since $a^\top x > 1$, this shows that $x\not\in (A^\circ)^\circ$.
This is a contradiction to your assumption.

Comment: Oh wow, that's super simple. I haven't thought of that yet. Thanks very much

Comment: This does work only if you already know $b > 0$ and this should follow from $0 \in A$. On the other hand, if $0 \not\in A$, the result does not hold since $0 \in (A^o)^o$.